# Functional difference between async Jest tests

Tags: jestjs

Is there a functional difference between these two asynchronous Jest tests?

```
await expect(myAsyncFunc()).resolves.toBe("My async func output")
```

```
expect(await myAsyncFunc()).toBe("My async func output")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally, there does not seem to be a difference. But the former seems idiomatic.

Consider that `myAsyncFunc` throws an error. In the former case, Jest prints the below:

> Received promise rejected instead of resolved
>
> Rejected to value: "Error"

In the latter case, Jest prints the below:

> thrown: "Error"

While we can deduce in the latter case that the function threw an error, the former is more descriptive and thus preferred.